# WordPress Translation Issue

Tags: translation

I tried to change text using the below code

```
function ctxtlearn_gettext( $ctxttranslation, $ctxttext ) {
   $ctxttrans = array_values(changeTxt_setting('trans',true));
   $ctxtdirty = false;
   $ctxtstrings_map = array();
   $ctxttext_words = explode( ' ', $ctxttext );

   foreach($ctxttrans  as $ctxtmytrans) {
       $ctxtstrings_map[$ctxtmytrans['key']] = $ctxtmytrans['val'];
   }

   foreach ( $ctxttext_words as $ctxtk => $ctxtword ) {
       $ctxtw = trim( $ctxtword, '.,:!?-_()' ); 
       if ( isset( $ctxtstrings_map[ $ctxtw ] ) ) {

           $ctxttext_words[ $ctxtk ] = str_replace( $ctxtw, $ctxtstrings_map[ $ctxtw ], $ctxtword );
           $ctxtdirty = true;
       }
   }

   if ( $ctxtdirty ) {
       return implode( ' ', $ctxttext_words );
   }
   return $ctxttranslation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'ctxtlearn_gettext', 10, 2 );
```

If i give the below input it works

```
Post => My Book
Page => My Vertical
Comments => My Feedback
```

The Word before => is old string and after that is new string. if i pass it as an array it work's. but if i provide the below input

```
First Name => My Name
Username => User ID
```

The username text changes but First Name Not Changing in profile page.
But if i split and provide its getting changed.

Who i can do this by providing Whole String..?

Comment: What has this to do with WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I itself found the answer..

below code is working

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {

     $words = array(
                        // 'word to translate' = > 'translation'
                        'Posts' => 'Article',
                        'Post' => 'Articles',
                        'Pages' => 'Stuffing',
                        'Media' => 'Upload Images',
                        'Links' => 'Blog Roll',
                    );

     $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are exploding the text with `explode( ' ', $ctxttext )`.
Therefore you are translating word by word, not strings.
That is why it's working with single word string, and not with multiple words.

When you call `First Name` you are translating `First` and `Name`.

Cheers

Comment: if i use like that then where ever the word first name or name is called will be changed.. i need the full parse to be changed when its called fully.. for eg if its called as `first` should not change.. if its called as `first name` it should change as `Your ID`

Comment: Yes, and that is why you need to remove the explode and implode parts from your function. Can you also paste the changeTxt_setting function code, so it's easier to see the problem?

Comment: i think you don't understand the exact issue